# Velocity, correct way to do it?

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

Basicly, I've tried to code velocity into my game, which works sort of. The deaccelaration works, but not just right.

My problem is, that theres no way for my velocity z and x, to reach 0, because it just fights between both positive and negative values, according to my code also.

But I can't see any other way, to stop this from happening, and decreasing correctly to 0.

**My code:**

```
if((!cc.isGrounded)) {
    velocity.y -= gravity;
}

if((velocity.z != 0)) {
    velocity.z = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.z, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
}

if((velocity.x != 0)) {
    velocity.x = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.x, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
}

if(isRightDown) {
    velocity.x = sidewayMovementSpeed;  
} else if(isLeftDown) {
    velocity.x = -sidewayMovementSpeed; 
}

if(isForwardDown) {
    velocity.z = forwardMovementSpeed;  
} else if(isBackDown) {
    velocity.z = -backwardMovementSpeed;
}
```

What I'm pretty much is asking, is there any different way to handle velocity, or is there a fix to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement some logic that will treat small values of velocity as 0, so that it wouldn't oscillate between positive and negative values.

**EDIT:**

Something like this

```
if(Math.Abs(velocity.x) > TOLERATED_VELOCITY)
{
    velocity.x = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.x, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
}
else
{
    velocity.x = 0;
}
```

where `TOLERATED_VELOCITY` is a constant specifying which values of velocity to consider zero.

Comment: That would just be a temopary solution, not very efficient. I've tried that, isn't much of a efficient solution.

Comment: Code sample? Isn't what I've provided enough? As I explained in my question, couldn't really figure out anyway else to do it.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen - I meant Dan, to enhance his answer, your only two ways of doing it are Dan's way and having a `applyVelocity` boolean

Comment: I saw your edit Dan, altho I can't see how this would be implemented. I've tried certain tricks with your code, but nothing seemed to work. I think I don't understand your code all that much :/.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen - The main point is that when the object reaches a velocity that is "almost zero" you just set the velocity to exactly zero